# How can I print a return value from a function in Java?

Tags: java, function, class, methods, constructor

I am writing a program for calculating pay for overtime hours and non-overtime hours. This is for my Java course, so the requirements are that I must have two classes and three functions. The first class does not have a main and contains three functions. It's basically where the calculation is done.The second class is for I/O, where you input your values through the Scanner and display the result.

I think I am almost done, however, I cannot get my total pay amount to return in my I/O class, it comes out as 0.0. *How can I get it to properly return my function **getPayAmount()** value?*

Here is the image of my first class, the three functions: constructor, payCalculation, and getPayAmount()

[image: Class-1.png]

Here is the image of my second class, where the I/O is done.

[image: Class-2.png]

Again, I'd like to know how I can return the value from my **getPayAmount()** function to print at my last sys.out statement.

Thanks so much in advance for your help, I'm so anxious to be done with this!

[image: Updated-Class-2.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating paycheck calculation after getting the input. move line 11 to 25

```
PayCheckCalculation myPay= new PayCheckCalculation (hours,rate);
myPay.payCalculation(rate,hours);
```

Comment: Thank you, I see how that'll initiate the variables to the input values, however, I'm still not printing payAmount from the first class. Am I using myPay.getPayAmount() incorrectly?

Comment: you have to call myPay.payCalculation(rate,hours); before getting getPayAmount

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the object `mypay`, the parameters are `rate` and `hours` have value as 0. Instead you want to instantiante the object with the values you get as input and you should get the right answer. Also you should use `this` in your class methods to refer to current object.

You did not call the method paycalculation method in your code as well.

Comment: Where would this. go in this program? I'm having trouble grasping this object-oriented concept

Answer (score 0):

In line 11 of your main function, you're creating the `mPay` object with `(0,0)` as initial values, you could initiate the object, you get the required information from the console or user, then the variables in the object will have updated values in them.

You could create or initiate the object after line 25 so that, you will have all the required data to calculate the payroll information from the user.

To understand an error, always check the flow of your code, this way you can find most of your errors.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've changed the code, and I can see that works now. The object myPay has the correct values by receiving the values from the user input now instead of 0,0. However, I seem to still not print out the value from payAmount() What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call the payCalculate function, after initializing the object, then it will work fine